# rails serverができない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

環境は、
ruby3.1
rails7.0
です。

```
rails new RailsApp
```

とコマンドに入力して、RailsAppフォルダ内に移動後、

```
rails server
```

と入力すると

```
C:\Users\陽子\Desktop\RailsApp>rails server
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
      [--skip-namespace], [--no-skip-namespace]              # Skip namespace (a
ffects only isolated engines)
      [--skip-collision-check], [--no-skip-collision-check]  # Skip collision ch
eck
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                          # Path to the Ruby
binary of your choice
                                                             # Default: C:/Ruby3
1-x64/bin/ruby.exe
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]                                  # Path to some appl
ication template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]                                  # Preconfigure for
selected database (options: mysql/postgresql/sqlite3/oracle/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/
jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                                             # Default: sqlite3
  -G, [--skip-git], [--no-skip-git]                          # Skip .gitignore f
ile
      [--skip-keeps], [--no-skip-keeps]                      # Skip source contr
ol .keep files
  -M, [--skip-action-mailer], [--no-skip-action-mailer]      # Skip Action Maile
r files
      [--skip-action-mailbox], [--no-skip-action-mailbox]    # Skip Action Mailb
ox gem
      [--skip-action-text], [--no-skip-action-text]          # Skip Action Text
gem
  -O, [--skip-active-record], [--no-skip-active-record]      # Skip Active Recor
d files
      [--skip-active-job], [--no-skip-active-job]            # Skip Active Job
      [--skip-active-storage], [--no-skip-active-storage]    # Skip Active Stora
ge files
  -C, [--skip-action-cable], [--no-skip-action-cable]        # Skip Action Cable
 files
  -A, [--skip-asset-pipeline], [--no-skip-asset-pipeline]    # Indicates when to
 generate skip asset pipeline
  -a, [--asset-pipeline=ASSET_PIPELINE]                      # Choose your asset
 pipeline [options: sprockets (default), propshaft]
                                                             # Default: sprocket
s
  -J, [--skip-javascript], [--no-skip-javascript]            # Skip JavaScript f
iles
      [--skip-hotwire], [--no-skip-hotwire]                  # Skip Hotwire inte
gration
      [--skip-jbuilder], [--no-skip-jbuilder]                # Skip jbuilder gem

  -T, [--skip-test], [--no-skip-test]                        # Skip test files
      [--skip-system-test], [--no-skip-system-test]          # Skip system test
files
      [--skip-bootsnap], [--no-skip-bootsnap]                # Skip bootsnap gem

      [--dev], [--no-dev]                                    # Set up the applic
ation with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge], [--no-edge]                                  # Set up the applic
ation with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
  --master, [--main], [--no-main]                            # Set up the applic
ation with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository main branch
      [--rc=RC]                                              # Path to file cont
aining extra configuration options for rails command
      [--no-rc], [--no-no-rc]                                # Skip loading of e
xtra configuration options from .railsrc file
      [--api], [--no-api]                                    # Preconfigure smal
ler stack for API only apps
      [--minimal], [--no-minimal]                            # Preconfigure a mi
nimal rails app
  -j, [--javascript=JAVASCRIPT]                              # Choose JavaScript
 approach [options: importmap (default), webpack, esbuild, rollup]
                                                             # Default: importma
p
  -c, [--css=CSS]                                            # Choose CSS proces
sor [options: tailwind, bootstrap, bulma, postcss, sass... check https://github.
com/rails/cssbundling-rails]
  -B, [--skip-bundle], [--no-skip-bundle]                    # Don't run bundle
install

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]                    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend], [--no-pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet], [--no-quiet]      # Suppress status output
  -s, [--skip], [--no-skip]        # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
  -h, [--help], [--no-help]        # Show this help message and quit
  -v, [--version], [--no-version]  # Show Rails version number and quit

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

    You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
    'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory,
    or in $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/rails/railsrc if XDG_CONFIG_HOME is set.

    Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
    defaults values shown above in this help message.

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

    This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
```

このように返されました。
そして、http://localhost:3000/
にアクセスしたところ、このサイトにアクセスできませんとエラーが出ました。
どうすれば。正常にページを表示できるでしょうか。

Comment: `RailsApp` フォルダで `bin/rails server` を実行するとどうなりますか。

Answer (score 0):

rails newコマンドで作成したアプリにcdコマンドで移動する必要があります。
rails newをした時にはまだrailsアプリの中には入っていないので、cdする必要があります

Comment: 質問では "RailsAppフォルダ内に移動後" に `rails server` を実行しているようです。